# Laravel VueJs | Frontend not catch pusher message

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a project, where vuejs and laravel connected as client, in other directory. The problem is vue js not catch message. I send message,in database saved successfully, in debug console(in pusher) we can see that message, but vue js not catch that moment

Bootstrap Js.

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'd7aad221315d2acb5356',
    cluster: 'ap2',
    // forceTLS: true,
    encrypted: true
});
```

Vue js package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "aos": "^2.3.4",
    "axios": "^0.21.4",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "laravel-echo": "^1.11.3",
    "pusher-js": "^7.0.3",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-click-outside": "^1.1.0",
    "vue-country-region-select": "^2.0.16",
    "vue-lottie": "^0.2.1",
    "vue-masked-input": "^0.5.2",
    "vue-moment": "^4.1.0",
    "vue-multiselect": "^2.1.6",
    "vue-pusher": "^1.1.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.2.0",
    "vue-slick-carousel": "^1.0.6",
    "vue-star-rating": "^1.7.0",
    "vue-video-player": "^5.0.2",
    "vuelidate": "^0.7.6",
    "vuex": "^3.6.2"
  },
```

I Try to solve this problem in main.js

```
Vue.use(require('vue-pusher'), {
  api_key: 'd7aad221315d2acb5356',
  options: {
    cluster: 'ap2',
    encrypted: true,
  }
});
```

As for me problem is either VueJs package Laravel Echo or Pusher-Js

Comment: can you show how you listen to the pusher channels?